# Can I generate stub from JAX RPC URL

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

Thanks in advance. I did not work too much on web services.

Client give me web service URL which is using JAX RPC. I want to consume it but i do not have wsdl URL for that web service URL. Can I generate stub from JAX RPC URL. This web service is authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Many web services will return the WSDL if you append `?wsdl` to the end of the service URL with which you were provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you have service url then probably you can have wsdl too? Try to append ?wsdl at the end of the service url you have.
Can you tell me what you get after doing aforementioned steps ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but I got website page with "Sorry, something went wrong" message.

I tried it by soapui with authorization and send xml(soapenv:Envelope tag) in request parameter. In soapui, i got response. Please help.